# Phonegap app for Apple's Newsstand

Tags: cordova, newsstand-kit

Does anyone know if it's possible to write a Phonegap app that can run in Apple's Newsstand? I've searched all over and have been only able to find threads like these:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/config_xml_setting_for_newsstand_application
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/newsstand

A lot of the stuff out there is unanswered or vague. Does anyone have any details on how to make this work?

Comment: Phonegap is cordova now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this solution that worked out great. If you need a publication on Apple's Newsstand, this will really help you out.

http://bakerframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

They don't have a plugin yet. But since Cordova has such a huge following, I wouldn't surprised if they have a plugin in a few years even months.

Answer (score 0):

**j3k0/PhoneGap-Newsstand-iOS** is a plugin that can be used to configure a PhoneGap application as a Newstand application, then change the cover icon to reflect the latest issue.

[j3k0/PhoneGap-Newsstand-iOS](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-Newsstand-iOS)

Tutorial here: http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/tutorial-for-phonegap-newsstand-applications/